# How to get user details from other jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins

We have a jenkins server hosted locally which contains build jobs both development and other environments.

It contains many other deployment jobs also.

So, we created one more jenkins server and moved some jobs there(Not complete clone).

Is there anyway to copy some files related to authentication so that, existing users will get login data to the new server also?

Answer (score 0):

Link I [tried](https://devopsdiaryblog.wordpress.com/2021/02/20/copy-jenkins-credentials-from-another-server/)

I copied below files and folders:

credentials-configuration.xml identity.key.enc secret.key.not-so-secret userContent
credentials.xml secret.key secrets users